# I'd like to validate a birthdate attribute to be over 18 years old

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm currently programming on ruby on rails with the devise gem. Added a birthdate to my user and I'm trying to validate the user being over 18 years old. I tried this, but it's not working.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
    def is_older?()
        (DateTime.now - :birth_date).to_i >= 6570

    end
  validates :birth_date, :presence =>{:if => {:is_older? =>{:message => 'You should be over 18 years old.'}}}



  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

end
```

I don't know if  :presence should be there but I added it so it wouldn't show any errors. Basically I'm trying to use an if statement as a validater if that is possible, which would be checking if the difference between the birth date the user tried to register and the date of today is higher than 18 years. 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be validating presence and age separately, and you can be using [`ActiveSupport::Duration`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html) for better date syntax (e.g., `18.years.ago`):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  validates :birth_date, :presence => true
  validate :validate_age

  private

  def validate_age
      if birth_date.present? && birth_date > 18.years.ago.to_d
          errors.add(:birth_date, 'You should be over 18 years old.')
      end
  end
end
```

Comment: Worked fine after changing ".to_d"  to ".to_i" and adding that same line to birth_date.
So the if statement would be:
if birth_date.present? && birth_date.to_i > 18.years.ago.to_i
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Hmm, I'm curious about the need to cast to an integer. I'd look at `birth_date.class.name` and `18.years.ago.class.name` and see if either needs to be cast to a date. Either way, I'm glad that you were able to get it working!

Comment: I think you're right and the cast to integer is not needed at all. Maybe it was just me trying to compare the date with 6570 (the amount of days in 18 years) where the cast would be needed. But your comment is totally valid and gives a more straightforward solution.
Thanks for your help @ChrisPeters

Comment: You're welcome. I understand what you were trying to accomplish and couldn't help but nudge you one last time. 

Comment: Thanks, but I only needed to change ".to_d" to ".to_date"